# on the carpet OR on a carpet

Tags: definite-article

> Yesterday evening I was visiting Jack’s and spilled some tea on **the**
> carpet.
>
> Yesterday evening I was visiting Jack’s and spilled some tea on **a**
> carpet.

It feels like both are correct. Are they correct indeed?

Comment: Would seem to be fine but to mean different things.  But a little more effort is needed than "I feel they are correct".

Comment: Have no idea. Just an assumption. The would mean there was only one carpet, A would mean there was more than one. But I am not sure.

Comment: I CV'd because I didn't see any research effort. Had OP done some research, I'm sure that he or she would have seen that this is a duplicate of several questions already on ELL.

Comment: If it's a duplicate then show me it

Answer (score 2):

In general, "the" refers to one specific thing, typically identified in the context, while "a" refers to any thing of that type. So, "I spilled tea on a carpet" means I spilled tea on some unspecified carpet. "I spilled tea on the carpet" means I spilled tea on one specific carpet.

In this case, "Yesterday evening I was visiting Jack's ..." likely means that you have one specific carpet in mind: the carpet at Jack's house. So normally in such a case we say "the".

Comment: OK, but my interlocuter doesn't know this carpet. Plus what if there is more than one carpet in his house?

Comment: _The carpet_ means 'the carpet I was on when I spilled the tea'! Similarly _I dropped it on the floor_ (the floor of the room I was in at the time) - _I looked out of the window_ (the window nearest to where I was).